# Passing arguments from command line to grunt copy task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

```
var pathValue="";

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [{
                    cwd: 'srcpath',  // set working folder / root to copy
                    src: '**/*',           // copy all files and subfolders
                    dest: 'pathValue',    // destination folder
                    expand: true
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.registerTask('copy', function(n) {
        var target = grunt.option('target');
        pathValue = target;
        // do something useful with target here
    });

};
```

I'm trying to pass destination path to the copy task from command line. I tired the command

grunt copy --target=destpath

It says "Done without errors" but new folder is not getting created in the destination directory. Can someone please tell me what's the error in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing dest to a qualified js file path. Like this:

```
dest: 'dest/bob.js'
```

Comment: You should be able to do that ultimately.  However, I would start by just hardcoding it to help you isolate the problem.  It sounds like a security problem or the path isn't properly specified.  I would start by making sure that the full file path exists and an editable .js file is already there that can be overwritten.  Good luck!